# Invalid password setting

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe

CnosDB version: cnosdb 2.3.2, revision 4e6bbdcc9144d4a69884cccdae197f2544d4fcc7
Mode: singleton

#### To Reproduce

1. Set config file `auth_enabled = false` and start cnosdb
2. Login consdb-cli as root, change password:

```
ALTER USER root SET PASSWORD = 'aaa';
```

3. Restart cnosdb, with config file setting `auth_enabled = true`
4. Login consdb-cli as root without password, it still managed to log in.